# C# Tidy up for classifying commands in for the command line game

Tags: c#

I am replicating a command-line based game and want accept the commands from players. It is how my code works right now.

```
    public static void GetCommand()
    {
        string? commandString = Console.ReadLine();
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(commandString))
        {
            GetCommand();
            return;
        }
        Classify(commandString);
    }

    private static void Classify(string? commandString)
    {
        if (commandString!.StartsWith("Help"))
        {
            //DoHelp
        }
        else if (commandString!.StartsWith("Save"))
        {
            //DoSave
        }
        else
        {
            GetCommand();
        }
    }
```

I want to implement more than 20/30 commands, possibly with respective **Arguments**, too. And if a user requests "help", I want to print all available commands and their descriptions. Is there any design pattern for this scenario to make much simpler?

Answer (score 0):

The command-pattern can be effective in this situation.

You have an `Command`-interface that defines operations like:

- `void execute(Context, string userInput)`,
- bool isApplicable(string userInput)`,
- and optionally `describeSelf()`

The concrete commands like `Help` and `Save` implement this interface.

You have a `CommandCollection` which has a method `executeFirstApplicable`.  This `CommandCollection` is passed to `Help` within the `Context`-argument of `execute()`.

If you want a more functional approach, the `execute`-method can accept and return a `GameState`.

Comment: is context an action for a command?

Comment: It's intended as a place to put stuff that any command could need to execute.  For example the web response you are building, an event bus where messages can be sent, or a display area on which can be drawn, effects of other entities in the game.  And the CommandCollection (for the Help command).  It's a bit ugly;  if you know a better way to pass this information or do without, than please do so.

Comment: I have been researching about Command Pattern for my case and I do not really get having an invoker class to keep track of commands since my scenario is just doing one simple command by one line.

Comment: The invoker would be the readline part and it uses CommandCollection to select the Command the user gives.  Perhaps executing should not be the responsibilty of CommandCollection, perhaps it should instead have `firstApplicable` to return the command to the invoker.